# Dealing with SQL cartesians in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, cartesian-product

I've got a query that is coming back with cartesians because one of the table joins can have many results. The use case is I have a company that can have many locations.

Here's the response I'm getting in my query:

```
[
  {
    // this is the company info
    oid: 31,
    companyName: 'Foo Bar Inc',
    avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100x100',
    bannerImage: 'http://placehold.it/800x200',

    // here starts the location
    name: 'Foo Bar Port',
    address: '1234 West 31 Street',
    city: 'New York',
    state: 'New York'
  },
  {
    oid: 31,
    companyName: 'Foo Bar Inc',
    avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100x100',
    bannerImage: 'http://placehold.it/800x200',

    name: 'Foo Bar Warehouse',
    address: '644 Main Street',
    city: 'Los Angeles',
    state: 'California'

  }
]
```

I would eventually like to get this to turn into:

```
{
  oid: 31,
  companyName: 'Foo Bar Inc',
  avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100x100',
  bannerImage: 'http://placehold.it/800x200',
  locations: [
    {
      name: 'Foo Bar Port',
      address: '1234 West 31 Street',
      city: 'New York',
      state: 'New York'
    },
    {
      name: 'Foo Bar Warehouse',
      address: '644 Main Street',
      city: 'Los Angeles',
      state: 'California'
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: There is no SQL in this post, no reference to a database engine, none of your code...?

Answer (score 0):

This below example if you use Sequelize ORM in node.js:

Here Company and Location is model.

```
// Company.js
// ...
  Company.associate = function(models) {
    // Using additional options like CASCADE etc for demonstration
    // Can also simply do Company.belongsTo(models.Location);
    Company.belongsTo(models.Location, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  }
// ...
```